# Showing UINavigationBar not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios6

I have a `UITabBarController` inside of a `UINavigationController` which originally had the navbar hidden before the view when the tabs were needed, though when I try to show the navbar inside the file nothing happens and if I do it just before the transition then it appears before I have pushed between the two controllers is there a way to stop this effect and make it so that when the next ViewController loads the navbar is on it when it appears?

This is not an OS specific issue as it occurs in iOS 6 and 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UITabBarController` class is not designed to be used as a child of a `UINavigationController`, which might explain why you're seeing odd behaviour. If you absolutely need a tab bar within a `UINavigationController`, you'll probably have to roll your own. Otherwise, make your `UITabBarController` the window's root view controller and populate it with navigation controllers.

Comment: I need the UINavigationBar initially hidden because of the push animation that can only be achieved by using it

Comment: You probably need to nest the nav controller in the tab bar controller rather than the other way around.

Comment: @nhgrif I don't want the first view which I am pushing from to be in the tabs

Comment: Then you need a modal segue to a tab bar controller, which has navigation controllers nested in it.

Comment: @rhgrif How would I do a modal segue

Comment: @rhgrif btw I am not using storyboards

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work it out though gave conmulligan the credit because he gave me the idea which was to keep the navigation bar hidden and to embed the viewcontroller inside a new navigationcontroller so there was a whole new navbar